# Enthought + PyCharm - cannot show plots anymore

Tags: python, plot, pycharm, enthought

I have on Mac OS X PyCharm with Enthought set up as interpreter:

```
~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User
```

However, it does not show any of the plots from matplotlib.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ts = pd.Series(random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
```

This just gives me `Out[124]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x10dd29f90>`. It does not show the plot, nor does it do anything else. No error, nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the call to the show() function that will display the plot items.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ts = pd.Series(random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
plt.show()
```

PyCharm is more than likely not configured in interactive mode with matplotlib.