# Expect to get a plot, but just get axes coordinates with Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, plot

I am trying to plot some very simple data using Pandas. I expect to get a graph output, but the only ouput is `Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)` What do I need to do to see an actual plot?

```
import pandas as pd
BabyDataSet = [('Bob', 968), ('Jessica', 155), ('Mary', 77), ('John', 578), ('Mel', 973)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = BabyDataSet, columns=['Names', 'Births'])
print df['Births'].plot()
```

Comment: Why are you printing here? won't `df['Births'].plot()` just work?

Comment: @EdChum removed the print and nothing happens. Code executes to end. Using PyCharm if that matters.

Comment: Try adding `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at top of your code and then after `df.plot()` do `plt.show()`

Comment: @EdChum That worked! Thanks. If you submit as an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is pycharm is not configured for interactive mode so you have to manually show the plot by doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd
# add this
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
BabyDataSet = [('Bob', 968), ('Jessica', 155), ('Mary', 77), ('John', 578), ('Mel', 973)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = BabyDataSet, columns=['Names', 'Births'])
df['Births'].plot()
# add this too
plt.show()
```

See related: [Enthought + PyCharm - cannot show plots anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856355/enthought-pycharm-cannot-show-plots-anymore)

As to why you see the axes, this is because that is what is returned when you call [`df.plot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot)

Answer (score 2):

First off, doing just `print df['Births'].plot()` prints the Axes object to the console. This only has data needed to help matplotlib plot the relevant information.

Second off, you need to import matplotlib. That handles graphing in pandas, not pandas itself.

Just do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

That should cause a graph with your relevant info to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't running iPython in pylab mode, have you tried importing matplotlib like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and then using `plt.show()` to show the plot